# looking for help proving conjecture about the sign of a polynomial, or finding counterexample

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

Math people:

I would like some help proving this conjecture, which is backed up by a lot of experiments, or finding a counterexample.  Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer, $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ be real numbers, and 
$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_0 x^k$, satisfying:

(i) $f(1) > 0$, that is, $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k > 0$,

(ii) $f(1)/2 \leq a_n \leq f(1)$, that is, $0 \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k \leq a_n$,

(iii) $f'(1) > 0$, that is, $\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k > 0$, and

(iv) $f'(1)/2 \leq na_n \leq f'(1)$, that is, $0 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} ka_k \leq na_n$.

My conjecture is that $f(x)$ must be positive for all $x>1$.  I have tested this numerically many times in Maple for many values of $n$, choosing the $a_k$'s from the uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$, then plotting $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ on an interval starting at $x =1$.  Every single time, the graph of $f$ appeared to be positive for $x > 1$.  I did find *one* example where $f'$ was negative for some $x>1$.  This happened with $n=9$, and

$\mathbf{a} = [                         -0.6192337770,
                          0.621280411,
                          0.944411120,
                          0.661825361,
                         -0.3978323268,
                          0.317857096,
                          0.504951983,
                         -0.9754565797,
                         -0.6667143676,
                          0.602928811]$.

I double-checked this by converting the components of $\mathbf{a}$ from floating-point numbers to fractions, to make sure roundoff error was not to blame, and $f$ really was decreasing for some $x > 1$.  However, $f(x)$ did appear to be positive for all $x > 1$, which is all I need.

This is the beginning of my Maple code:

```
restart: 
randomize():#not sure what this does or if it is necessary
            #Might need it to ensure different random values for 
            #different experiments
n:=9;#degree of polynomial
while 1=1 do
   for j from 0 to n do
     a[j]:=2.0*rand()/(1000000000000.0)-1.0: 
   end do: #for j...
   f0at1:=add(a[j],j=0..n):
   f1at1:=add(j*a[j],j=1..n):
   if ((f0at1 > 0) and (f1at1 > 0) and 
      (a[n]>f0at1/2.0) and (a[n] < f0at1) and
      (a[n]>f1at1/2.0) and (a[n] < f1at1)) then
      break:#break out of infinite loop
   end if:
end do: #while 1=1 ...

f:=z->add(a[j]*z^j,j=0..n);
```

Because of the near-counterexample I found, I am going to write a loop that repeatedly produces $f$, finds its minimum value on $[1,\infty)$, and halts if the minimum is negative.

Comment: Did you omit an assumption that the coefficients of $f$ have absolute value less than or equal to 1?  Otherwise $f(x)=(x-1)^3 - 100(x-1)^2 + 4(x-1) + 1$ is a counterexample.  (I wrote it that way because that's how I constructed it.  It made sense to shift the focus from $f(1)$ to $g(0)$, where $g(x)=f(x+1)$, noting that the lead coefficient is $a_n$ for both.  I did all this before reading carefully your description of the numerical tests, where you do use a restriction on all the coefficients.)

Comment: @Barry The inequalities are scale-invariant, if you really have a counter-example then you can just divide $f$ by a million and it will still be a counter-example and have small coefficients

Comment: @BarryCipra : no, there is no such assumption.  I just needed some way of generating random numbers, and the simplest way was with a uniform distribution.  I am surprised I did not find a counterexample in so many trials.  If you make your comment an answer, and I can verify for myself that it works, I will accept it, unless someone beats you to it (I see as I type that 2 answers have appeared!)

Comment: @user2566092, you're right, thanks.  I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Barry doesn't your example violate condition (ii) when you expand it out?  I seem to get $x^3 - 103x^2 + 207x - 1$, and the sum of the trailing coefficients looks bigger than the leading coefficient of 1.

Comment: @user2566092 : I think Barry's example works.  You don't have to expand out the polynomial, it's easier to find and use $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$.  I also found a counterexample with $n=3$ using my Maple experiment.

Comment: @user2566092, the expansion is $x^3-103x^2+207x-104$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a counterexample by shifting the focus from $f(1)$ to $g(0)$, where $g(x)=f(x+1)$.  Note that the lead coefficient of $g(x)$ is the same as $f(x)$, namely $a_n$.  Writing $g(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + b_1x+b_0$, we have $f(1)=g(0)=b_0$ and $f'(1)=g'(0)=b_1$, so the essential inequalities are

$$0\le b_0\le 2a_n\le2b_0$$

(for i and ii) and

$$0\le b_1\le 2na_n\le 2b_1 $$

(for iii and iv).  Now let $n=3$ and $a_n=1$, which leaves the inequalities $b_0\le2\le2b_0$ and $b_1\le6\le2b_1$, which can satisfied by letting $b_0=1$ and $b_1=4$.  The polynomial

$$g(x)=x^3+b_2x^2+4x+1$$

can clearly be made negative for some $x>0$ by choosing an extremely large *negative* value for $b_2$, such as $b_2=-100$.  Finally, returning to $f$, we have the counterexample

$$f(x)=g(x-1)=(x-1)^3 - 100(x-1)^2 + 4(x-1) + 1$$

for which the inequalities i-iv are satisfied but $f(2)=-94\lt0$.  (It's clear that $b_2=-10$ would also have worked.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying random polynomials, I suggest the following approach: For some choices of $x$ (and $n$) solve the linear program in the unknonwns $a_0,\ldots a_n$
$$\sum a_k x^k\stackrel !=\min\qquad$$
subject to 
$$0\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k\le a_n  $$ 
$$0\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ka_k\le na_n  $$ 
and see if that minimum turns out to be negative for suitable $x>1$.
Plotting the minimum against $x$ may give valueable insights.

Answer (score 0):

Since my first answer was incorrect, I am trying again, hopefully with a better result:

Let$f(x)=1+3(x-1)-5(x-1)^2+3/4(x-1)^3$; then $f(1)=1$, $f^\prime (1)=3$, but $f(2)=-1/4$.

Comment: The OP is asking if $f(x)\gt0$ for all $x\gt1$, not $x\gt0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my initial answer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because you fixed it.  I think downvotes should be used for when people show off or give an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan.  (I should have checked my work better, though.)